# Two responses both inflicted by measurement error. How to deal with outliers

Tags: outliers

Let $y_1$ = 'time spent sleeping per day' and $y_2 = $ 'time spent resting per day'. (Note: these are two distinct activities).

Such responses were gathered from a group of animals. There are also other responses like $y_3 = $ 'hunting frequency'.

The issue is now that about 20 % of the data set has $y_2 = 0$ almost always. This is almost certainly a measurement error due to a flawed electronic device, since it is known that these animals rest a considerable amount of time every day. Further, it is almost certain that the actual time spent resting has instead been added to $y_1$.

Therefore, the other responses, like $y_3$, have no problems, even for this 20 % of the data. The only issue is the mish-mash of $y_1$ and $y_2$, for this 20 % of the data.

Which approach is now adequate?

1. Create a new response $\bar{y} = y_1 + y_2$, with the interpretation "time spent either resting or sleeping", and use the entire data set. The issue with this is that there's a huge difference between sleeping and resting, so we lose a lot of information.
2. Analyse $y_3, y_4, ...$ etc., with the entire data set. Then, delete the 20 %, and use this subset of the data to analyse $y_1$ and $y_2$.
3. Delete the 20 %, and use them to analyse $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, ....$ etc.
4. ???